# Google Rich Snippets JobPosting not displaying

Tags: html, seo, schema, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

I have added the necessary Schema markup for the JobPosting schema to my job board website. However, the rich snippets are not showing up in SERPs unlike one of my competitors.

Am I missing any mandatory fields?

I have checked the webmaster tools Structured Data tool and everything looks fine.

Here is an example screenshot:

[image: Screenshot SERPs]

Any helps greatly appreciated.

My URL: http://www.backpackerjobboard.com.au/jobs-in/sydney/

EDITED: acode snippet added

`<ul class="jobs-list">
    <li class="group" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">
        <div class="inner">
            <span class="status"><span>&middot;</span> New</span>
            <h3><a href="http://www.backpackerjobboard.com.au/job/15614/qualified-joiners-and-cabinet-makers-wanted-immediate-start-at-nsw-joinery-pty-ltd/" title="Qualified Joiners and Cabinet Makers wanted Immediate start"><span itemprop="title">Qualified Joiners and Cabinet Makers wanted Immediate start</span></a></h3>
            <span class="company-name" itemprop="hiringOrganization" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"><span itemprop="name">NSW Joinery Pty Ltd</span></span>
            <span class="location"><i class="icon">&nbsp;</i>
                <span itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
                    <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
                        <span itemprop="addressRegion">Sydney</span>
                    </span>
                </span>
            </span>
            <span class="time-posted" itemprop="datePosted">Job posted: 21st November 2014</span>

        </div>
        <span class="category" itemprop="employmentType">Full-time</span> 
    </li>
...
</ul>`

Comment: How long ago did you publish the snippets?

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question ([edit]), otherwise this question will be of no use to anyone else when you change the code on your site.

Comment: No problem - totall understand;

Comment: The snippets were added about 6 months ago.